# Calling a python script from a django project

Tags: python, django

I'm working my way through https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/. In this there is a discussion of calling a view  and connecting the a url to a view.  Can this also work for a django app or a script that does not contain a view?

Let's assume that if I had an app called 'myapp' with a script called 'myscript', I assume I would do something like

myapp/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from myapp import myscript

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', ???myscript???, name='myapp')
)
```

does this conform to best practices, or if not how should I call the script from inside a django project

Comment: 'script' is a loose word. What do you mean by it exactly? Code in a standalone `.py` file? A function not in your views file? Something else?

Comment: No need to overcomplicate it .Just define a viewmethod that this URL calls. Then, call the method on the py file just like you would normally.

Comment: Bitgarden, yes I meant either a django app or a standalone .py file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing special about a Django view: it's simply a function (or other callable) that takes a request and returns a response. There's no limitation on where the function lives, what it's called, what its module is called, whether it's inside a Django app, or anything.

That said, if your "script" is a function that doesn't do either of those things, you probably want to have a separate view that does, and which calls your separate function. Again, you can simply import that within your views file, and call it directly inside the view.

Answer (score 2):

Django expects a function to handle particular url and with some constraints like:

- First parameter passed is `HttpRequest` object
- The function must return appropriate `HttpResponse` object.

It does not matter where the function resides either in `views.py` or any other python file.